# get the value from an array of object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

i am new to `lodash` and `Javascript`. Here, I have following array of object,

```
const bgStatus =
   [{
     Id: "809"
     Name: "PRE"
    Description: "PRE"
    Value: "VP:PRE"
    },
    {
     Id: "809"
     Name: "CLO"
    Description: "CLO"
    Value: "VP:CLO"
    },
    {
     Id: "809"
     Name: "BU"
    Description: "BU"
    Value: "VP:BU"
    }
    ]
```

Now, I want to get only description value if it matches with the value key.

So, I tried,

```
currentStatus  = "VP:PRE"
```

Now,

```
const obj =   _.find(buyingSessionStatus,{Value: this.currentStatus});
```

and when I did obj.Description then I am not getting the result which I was expecting to be `PRE`

Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: provided that your objects in your array are the correct syntax (with commas after each key-value pair), and that `buyingSessionStatus` is the `bgStatus` array you've shown in your question and `this.currentStatus` is equal to `"VP:PRE"`, your code will work fine. Your issue is either a syntax error due to the invalid objects in your array or `buyingSessionStatus` or `this.currentStatus` not being what you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Lodash:**

```js
const currentStatus = "VP:PRE";
const obj = _.find(bgStatus, status =>
                      currentStatus === status.Value)
```

**Using Vanilla Javascript:**

```js
const currentStatus = "VP:PRE";
const obj = bgStatus.find(status => 
               currentStatus === status.Value);
console.log(obj.description); // "PRE"
```